# HDR sky makes light stains on background photo in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, hdri

I have a panoramatic PNG photo making a background of the scene (warps around the scene). I have recently added a HDR sky from Blenderkit; it looks nice, but I think it's a culprit for the stains on the background photo I get in Cycles rendering result.

[image: stains]

The sky is the HDR sky, the forrests and bellow are from PNG with transparent background above the horizon (for the sky to be rendered there). The PNG has transparency, is set to alpha clipping.
Before applying the HDR sky, there were no stains on the background.

I'm still a newbie, only using Blender for about 20 years :-D (very very leisurely) and don't know what information would be relevant in this case; I will complete it as per comments, if required. Here is the shading structure:

[image]

To me it almost looks like the sky lighting is not scaled the same as the sky texture and is in front of the background photo.
Any suggestions appreciated.